# alert because of one of JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript

In our application we have a lot of JavaScript functions and sometimes an "[object Error]" alert comes out from nowhere when using IE7. It happens sometimes. The problem is that I can't figure out which exact function is causing that error. Any hint on how I can debug this?

Thanks.

Comment: searched for `alert` in the source code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base on [this article](https://www.adaptavist.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27723664), it is a bug in IE7

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IE, then when there is an error in your JavaScript code, there will be an error indicator on the left bottom of the browser window, you can click it to see which line of the JS code goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Developer Tools debugger and select Break on Error.

Comment: That's the problem. I can't reproduce this problem. It doesn't happen always. It happens on very rare occasions. I was asking - is there a way besides of debugging to find, identify, etc. what exact function is causing this issue. What methods are not allowed in IE which may cause such an issue, etc.